# Php not writing to serial port

Tags: php, serial-port, arduino, debian

I've been experimenting with my arduino for a while now. A few weeks ago, I decided I wanted to be able to control it through a website.
My webserver is running on Linux turnkey (That's a debian distro) but it also is not working on my Ubuntu 14.02 LTS running inside vBox (usb is configured correctly, again, works using screen)

I am running php 5.4.4-14+deb7u10 and apache 2.2.22

I have identified arduino's port to be /dev/ttyACM0, I can send data to it using `(sudo) screen /dev/ttyACM0` but it is not working with the following code:
This code is a direct copy of [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-an-Arduino-with-PHP/)

```
<?php


$verz="1.0";
$comPort = "/dev/ttyACM0";

if (isset($_POST["rcmd"])) {
$rcmd = $_POST["rcmd"];

switch ($rcmd) {
     case Stop:
        $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
        fwrite($fp, 1);
        echo 'Stop, 1';
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    case Slow:
        $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
        fwrite($fp, 2);
        fclose($fp);
        echo 'Slow operation, 2';
        break;
    case Medium:
        $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
        fwrite($fp, 3);
        fclose($fp);
        echo 'Medium operation, 3';
        break;
    case Fast:
        $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
        fwrite($fp, 4);
        fclose($fp);
        echo 'Fast operation, 4';
        break;
    case Right:
        $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
        fwrite($fp, 5);
        fclose($fp);
        echo 'Right operation, 5';
        break;
    case Left:
        $fp =fopen($comPort, "w");
        fwrite($fp, 6);
        fclose($fp);
        echo 'Left operation, 6';
        break;
    default:
        die('Crap, something went wrong. The page just puked.');
}

}
?>
<html>
<body>

<center><h1>Arduino from PHP Example</h1><b>Version <?php echo $verz; ?></b></center>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
<input type="submit" value="Left" name="rcmd">
<input type="submit" value="Right" name="rcmd"><br/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Stop" name="rcmd"><br/>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Slow" name="rcmd">
<input type="submit" value="Medium" name="rcmd">
<input type="submit" value="Fast" name="rcmd">
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Yes, I know, badly written code. I know, but it is not my code and I didn't feel like changing it.

I have also tried it using the php_serial library, which also doesn't work.

Comment: Could it be something simple like you need a cross-over/null-modem cable?

Comment: @cup found out what the problem was, arduino bootloader requires a 2 second dly after I opening a port in ortldee to be avle to receove a msg